# I Can not install skype on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: skype, dependencies

I can't install skype on Ubuntu 12.10, I need your help.

This is the error:

`Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:`

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

SO?

Comment: How are you trying to install skype? Just open Ubuntu Software Center and install skype from there. No need to download it from the Skype site.

Comment: still getting the same error dear, the difference is, in Terminal, it gives detailed error while by installing software center it gives pop up menu for the same error. the error is due to skype-bin.

Comment: Where you originally trying to install skype through the deb file on the Skype site? If this is so, try going to "Software Sources" and under "other" check if there are any skype ppas. Disable them and try `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install skype`

Comment: Already did that, no help.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install skype-bin` then `sudo apt-get install skype`

Comment: Had the same problem, solved it by changing repository servers.

Answer (score 4):

If you have problems with

> unmet dependencies: skype-bin

try this from terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype-bin skype
```

**before execute above commands** be sure that canonical-partners repository is enabled.

Check it from

Update Manager > Settings > Other Software

[image]

Comment: thanks but no help, problem still remains with this error. "arsalan@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install skype-bin skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package skype-bin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'skype-bin' has no installation candidate
arsalan@ubuntu:~$ 
"

Comment: @Arsalan, probably is not your mistake then. Skype package is [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype) and the binary `skype-bin` is [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/skype-bin), maybe something happened with the repos. Wait 1-2 days and try again. Do not forget to update first, `sudo apt-get update` .

Comment: Man come on, no solution yet? I still cant install it.

Comment: I am still looking for response pls..

Comment: Have you tried to change server ? Update Manager > Settings > Download From: > change it to main or something else.

Comment: still not working ;(

Comment: Download [skype-bin](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_partner/quantal/partner/base/skype-bin) and install it manually.

Comment: I tried to download it before, but when I click on 64 bit edition to download, the next page comes up with 404 not found :S .. phewwww, this is getting better and better.

Comment: Finally, I got it installed, thank you everyone for the help, there was something wrong with the repos, now its fine I installed using skype-bin command, thanks again.

Comment: I told you , you have to wait.. :-) Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed it using dynamic package on the skype webpage http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/
When you go to that webpage it would show you a drop down, and there you have to choose the 'Dynamic' one.

Download it, then unpack it using archive manager, and when you open the folder you would see the skype icon, click on it and thats it!